# export in bash with printf doen't work

Tags: python, linux, bash, export, env

I exported:

```
export FMTSTR="%2\$n'printf "\xc0\xf2\x03\x42";'"
```

and I want to see the result:

```
env | grep FMTSTR
FMTSTR=%2$n'printf xc0xf2x03x42;'
```

but this is not what I want...The result must be :

```
‫‪FMTSTR=%2$nTB‬‬
```

Could you possibly tell me what the problem is?
secondly can I use python instead of printf? like this:

```
export FMTSTR="%2\$n $(python -c 'print "\xc0\xf2\x03\x42"')"
```

when I use python the result is:

```
FMTSTR=%2$n ��B
```

why?
please give me a help in these two questions.

thank you...

Comment: Can you please show us an "ideal output"? What do you want it to equal in the end?

Comment: I told friend.The result must be: ‫‪FMTSTR=%2$nTB‬‬

Comment: Why are you escaping the hex literals while setting the variable?

Comment: what do you mean?  I didn't get it, pardon

Comment: can you gime me an example?

Comment: I tried `$printf "\xc0\xf2\x03\x42"`  and got ��B.
Also I tried `$python -c 'print "\xc0\xf2\x03\x42"'` and got the same: ��B.
There is something with your terminal encoding (for me it is UTF8). Try playitng with this:

    $python -c 'print "\xc0\xf2\x03\x42".decode("cp1251").encode("utf8")'

Comment: my result is: FMTSTR=%2$n АтB...I think i'm getting closed...thank you..but 'A' char is extra...

Comment: I don't see where the TB comes from. I see the \x42 'B' in ascii, but what are the 3 bytes before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly correct (due to the nature of your question), but I feel you may have better luck using this:

```
export FMTSTR=`python -c 'print "%2$n\xc0\xf2\x03\x42"'`
```

Now, the `\xc0\xf2\x03` has no ascii equivalent. I'm not sure how you're expecting the output TB.